# VBA Help on Splitting Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that I need to split out.  For example I have columns A, B, C and D and I need to split the sheet out so:

1st Sheet - columns A & B
2nd Sheet - columns A & C
3rd sheet - columns A & D

This is for approximately 350 columns and column A needs to be the constant.

I have the below code:

```
Sub t()
Dim lc As Long, sh As Worksheet, newSh, ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Set sh = ActiveSheet
With sh
    lc = .Cells.Find("*", , xlValues, xlPart, xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
    For i = 1 To lc
        If Application.CountA(.Columns(i)) > 0 Then
        
            Set newSh = Sheets.Add
            ws1.Range("a:a").Copy Range("a:a")
            Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns(i)).Copy newSh.Range("A1")
            newSh.Copy
        
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs newSh.Range("a1").Value & ".xlsx"
            ActiveWorkbook.Close
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            newSh.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

But this only splits out the individual columns, I need to add column A each time

Comment: Your code appears to create new workbooks instead of new sheets, and then save the workbooks individually, is that the desired result? Or do you want all the sheets in the same workbook?

Comment: Sorry, new workbooks is the desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this bit of code:

```
ws1.Range("a:a").Copy Range("a:a")
Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns(i)).Copy newSh.Range("A1")
```

You output to column A both times. So column A is copied each time, but overwritten by whichever other column you copy. Fix this by outputting to `"B1"` on the second line.

Comment: Thank you!  I can see my error now, this has worked perfectly